# Prevent stock keyboard app from being activated while/after connecting physical keyboard?

Tags: external-keyboard, swiftkey

I have a Samsung I9305 with rooted stock 4.4.4.. I have Xposed framework.

I use SwiftKey.

When I use a Bluetooth or OTG keyboard, SwiftKey is automatically disabled and the stock keyboard is enabled.

Is it possible to

1. Prevent the change of keyboard and have SwiftKey continue even while using the physical keyboard?
2. At least make the system automatically change back to SwiftKey after the physical keyboard is disconnected?

Comment: Possible. See [my answer here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/131642/16575) , plus another one [here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/96045/16575) :)

Comment: @Izzy I'm sure your solution would have worked fine, but I found a simpler way to do it. I have posted it as an answer.

Comment: Glad to read you've been able to solve the issue your way! I must have misread a little (didn't notice you don't want to switch between keyboards, but wanted to use a sole keyboard other than the default). I've re-formatted your answer a little, hope you like it that way (+1 btw). Another warning hint: with the OS default keyboard unavailable, there might be issues with lock screen (enter password/pin) as well as encryption (same thing), which might rely on the "stock keyboard". We had such cases reported here already.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the edit and info. During the next few days I will evaluate if there are any glitches with my phone and come back here to make necessary edits if I find any. By the way, you can make the Tasker method as a second answer. Some readers may prefer that answer.

Comment: Glad you like the edit! As the Tasker variant is linked from there, I see no reason to duplicate it – can be found easily this way. In case you need to edit the answer again, feel free to make that link bold if you like :) Now: Shall we do a little comment-cleanup? Several of them got obsolete by now. I'll start that already.

Comment: @Izzy I've already discovered one disadvantage of my answer. I've edited it to reflect it.

Comment: I've also added some details from my previous comment, please cross-check.

Comment: Great. With my particular ROM there are no problems with the lock screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Root App Deleter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=zsj.android.systemappremover) to disable the stock keyboard app. That way I just keep using *SwiftKey* whether using physical keyboard or not.

**Note:** SwiftKey only lets me use the English layout when using a physical keyboard. I normally type in both English and Norwegian, and like to switch between layouts. The Samsung stock keyboard let me easily do this by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>. As far as I can see, Swiftkey has me locked onto English layout when using a physical keyboard. **If you want to be able to switch between different layouts, you will be better off using the [Tasker method suggested by Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131642/16575).**

With SwiftKey, the soft keyboard disappears from the screen as soon as the physical keyboard is connected. One catch is that there is annoying message I have to click <kbd>OK</kbd> to every time I connect the physical keyboard, but that is okay. It just amounts to a simple press of the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

#### Warnings:

- This method worked on my particular device and ROM, but there is no guarantee that it will work on other devices and/or ROMs. The app I linked to above requires root. ***Do NOT delete the stock keyboard app of your device,*** just disable it. Even disabling the stock keyboard app of your device may in some rare devices and ROMs cause the system to misbehave. If that happens to you you can use the same app to reenable the stock keyboard app again, and use the [Tasker method suggested by Izzy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/131642/16575) in the comments instead.
- A very small number of Android ROMs may be unable to reenable apps after having disabled them with this app. The app has a test module that you should run before disabling any apps, to make sure that reenabling them again will work.
- With the OS default keyboard unavailable, there *might* be issues with lock screen (enter password/pin) as well as encryption (same thing), which might rely on the "stock keyboard". Such cases already have been reported here – see e.g. [How to enter password for decrypt without system keyboard on android](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/79013/16575). Especially for the encryption password, this is a logical consequence: the user-installed keyboard app is stored on the user partition (`/data`), which is encrypted – so the keyboard cannot be loaded before that partition is decrypted, which requires the user to enter the passphrase; a typical dead-lock situation..
- In general, use this (and all other) root apps at your own risk, and backup your system with [clockworkmod](/questions/tagged/clockworkmod)/[twrp](/questions/tagged/twrp) regularly if you have a rooted device and use root-applications.